# Trouble with backslash in Tcl exec

Tags: postgresql, tcl, exec

I am writing a data import script in Tcl (from SQL Server to Postgres) and have to call command line unix `tr` to scrub out null characters in a data file.  I write the data to a temp file and then use `exec` to process the file through `tr`.

The `tr` call I would like Tcl to generate looks like this on the command line:

```
tr -d '\000' < blah >blah.notnull
```

The Tcl code I use to make the above is this, with `$STATE(TMP)` holding the temp file:

```
set ret [catch {exec tr -d '\\000' < $STATE(TMP) > $STATE(TMP).clean}]
```

However, sometimes this doesn't work and the PostgreSQL COPY fails because of x00 characters.  If I run the command line version on the file, then COPY succeeds.

Could someone help me out understanding the exec call and quoting and backslashes?  I am a bit stumped.

The error message, a reformatted version of the PG error:

```
Problem with COPY on blahblah: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR, ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

Annoyingly, the Tcl `exec` code often works, but not always.

(We are hand rolling an import system using Tcl, Linux, BCP, SQL server, etc. beause all the off-the-shelf tools fail with the size of our data.)

Thanks to all who read or answer!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Tcl doesn't ascribe any special meaning at all to single quotes. The equivalent in Tcl is braces, so use `{\000}` instead of `'\000'`. With what you wrote, you were sending three characters (a `'`, a NUL, and another `'`) in as that argument, and that causes all sorts of trouble since literal NUL characters don't go well as C strings.

Thus, you should be doing:

```tcl
exec tr -d {\000} < blah >blah.notnull
```

or:

```tcl
set ret [catch {
    exec tr -d {\000} < $STATE(TMP) > $STATE(TMP).clean
}]
```

---

Tcl can also do that operation directly.

```tcl
# Read binary data
set f [open $STATE(TMP) "rb"]
set data [read $f]
close $f

# Write transformed binary data
set f [open $STATE(TMP).clean "wb"]
puts -nonewline $f [string map [list \u0000 ""] $data]
close $f
```

[EDIT]: When the amount of data being transformed is large, it's better to do a bit at a time.

```tcl
set fIn [open $STATE(TMP) "rb"]
set fOut [open $STATE(TMP).clean "wb"]
while true {
    # 128kB chunk size; a bit arbitrary, but big enough to be OK
    set data [read $fIn 131072]
    # If we didn't read anything and instead got EOF, stop the loop
    if {[eof $fIn]} break
    puts -nonewline $fOut [string map [list \u0000 ""] $data]
}
close $fIn
close $fOut
```

You could also use a Tcl 8.6 channel transform to do the work and then `fcopy` to move things over, but there wouldn't be much difference in performance.

Comment: Donal - is there a way to capture the interpeted string that exec is exec-ing?  Your code runs without an error, but I am not able to get final desired effect and my postgres COPY is still failing; I was hoping to look at exactly how it is executing. And the reason I don't do the direct Tcl version is because the files are often 15G or so.  Tx!

Comment: Ah, for 15GB you want to stream it or chunk it. Easily done now that I know it's an issue. The string is what it says on the tin, so to speak; there are three words: `tr`, `-d`, and `\000` (they are not one string on Unix; the word boundaries are preserved on all POSIX platforms). The rest is redirection.

Comment: Thanks Donal for your help!  I still would like to know how to better diagnose the shell call as passed through exec.  Even if we don't use it here, I will be using the shell for other things in the future, and I know that running your command versus the command line version gives different results, so I would like to get to the bottom of it.